# How can I fix my java Stack<T> code where I got nullpointerexception?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, stack

> Create a Stack  generic class that represents a stack (placing an item on top of the stack, removing an item from the top of the stack, querying the topmost item, querying the size, throwing exceptions in case of errors)!

How can I fix this? I do not have any idea.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Stack<T> {
    private T[] stack = null;
    private int size = 0;

    public void push(T x) {
       stack[size] = x;
       size++;
      }
    public T pop() throws Exception{
        if (size == 0) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Cannot pop from empty stack");
        }else{
            size--;
            return stack[size];
        }
     }
    public T top() throws Exception {
        if (size == 0) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("The stack is empty");
        }else{
            return stack[size-1];
        }
      }
    public int size() {
       return size;
      }

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    
    Stack<Integer> stack1 = new Stack<Integer>();

        stack1.push(213);
        stack1.push(345);
        stack1.push(987);

        while(stack1.size() > 0){
            System.out.println(stack1.pop());
        }

        System.out.println("\n");

        Stack<String> stack2 = new Stack<String>();

        stack2.push("1");
        stack2.push("2");
        stack2.push("3");
        stack2.push("4");

        while(stack2.size() > 0){
            System.out.println(stack2.pop());
        }
    
}
}

I got an error message :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Stack.push(Stack.java:12)
        at Stack.main(Stack.java:41)
```

Comment: The `T[] stack` is always `null`. Instantiate it inside the constructor with a default capacity and check inside your `push` method if there is still space left. If not copy all elements to a larger array and continue.

Comment: Any particular reason why you use an Array as the stack? Have you considered using an (Array)List instead? It's a bit easier to add and remove items from them since they automatically become bigger to store more items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the line `private T[] stack = null;` You don't initialize an array. Therefore you get NullPointerException when calling `pop()`, `top()`, `push(t)`on it.

What you miss is a constructor for your stack, where you pass the max capacity for the stack and after that you have to initialize an array with that size.

```java
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class Stack<T> {
    private final int capacity; // remember capacity
    private final Object[] stack; // array of type Object
    private int size = 0;

    public Stack(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.stack = new Object[capacity]; // initialize new array
    }

    public void push(T x) {
        if (size == capacity) { // check for sufficient capacity
            throw new IllegalStateException("Stack is full.");
        }
        stack[size] = x;
        size++;
    }
    public T pop() {
        if (size == 0) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Cannot pop from empty stack");
        }else{
            size--;
            return (T) stack[size]; // cast result
        }
    }
    public T top() {
        if (size == 0) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("The stack is empty");
        }else{
            return (T) stack[size-1]; // cast result
        }
    }
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

Note, that capacity is the max size of data your stack can maintain and size would be the currentl capacity in use. You would also check for sufficient capacity before pushing something onto it. As
[@rzwitserloot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/768644/rzwitserloot) mentioned is the creation of an generic array not trivial, the easiest would be to create an Object array and casting the retrieval of their entries.

Otherwise (which is much more complicated) you have to dynamically resize the backend array when adding something to it, while it is full or switch the array for an ArrayList.

Comment: Downvoted for now (I think it's salvagable and invite you to do it): You simply say 'you forgot to initialize the array', but this obviously leads to the question: "So how do I do that?", and initializing a `T[]` variable is quite the conundrum, so it by no means 'can be left unsaid' or 'as an exercise to the reader'. Suggested salvage route: Add to it should probably be `Object[]` instead, or a `List<T>`. NB: Your edit isn't helping - `new T[capacity]` does not compile.

Comment: This code still doesn't compile (it's just `public Stack(int capacity)`, no `<T>`), and you should perhaps mention something about needing to rewrite the field as `private Object[] stack` instead.